# Why my loading gif makes my page to load slower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

I used some code to display a gif before my page load but it is 
increasing  my page's loading speed...

Here is where I use that code - http://sarkarinaukrihome.com/

JS

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("fast");;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

CSS

```
.no-js #loader {
  display: none;
}

.js #loader {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}

.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(Preloader_2.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

Comment: plzz help me fast i want to either reduce the loading time or instantly disappear the gif after the page load half plzz help and i have used code here see it and answer- http://sarkarinaukrihome.com/

Comment: "Increase page load speed" means the page is loaded faster, I'd assume you're meaning the gif slows down the page load?

Comment: yes exactly the gif slower down the loading speed

Comment: How did you measure page load speed?

Comment: i use google Analytics to measure the speed before i used that  code it was 1 sec but after using code it became 5-10 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **resize** to the exact desired dimensions of your HTML container and **compress** all images.

If you look closely at your network flow, you lose a lot of time to load all the images.

[image: Network viewer]

If you analyze the performance of your website, Google Chrome gives you recommendations and you have precisely this point mentioned with the possible gain if you perform the suggested actions.

[image: Audit viewer]

To use the **LightHouse Viewer** of Google Chrome, read [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/)

For the **theoretical concept** of image compressing, you can read [this](https://web.dev/serve-images-with-correct-dimensions/)

**To compress** different images, you can use services like [this](https://compressjpeg.com/fr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the picture below the differents loading times of your website's files...
Your image `quiz.png` seems quite fat so it will take some time to load it...

As you just use it in a small format, you maybe should reduce its size ! ;)

Also, notes that your website is searching for some `LOGO.png` that it doesn't find ... ( doesn't really matters though )

With chrome's inspector :

[image]